# Android ImageView Selector Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, selector

I'm runnin' in a strange issue, I'm designing a home screen widget with 2 ImageView that will be used as buttons for left and right navigation. I made 2 selectors for those imageview with the different states, but when executing and clicking on button the second is also highlighted with the first :

1st Selector : widget_right_selector.xml

```
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_prev_active" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_prev_active" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_prev_active" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/widget_prev" />
</selector>
```

2nd Selector : widget_left_selector

```
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_next_active" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_next_active" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_next_active" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/widget_next" />
</selector>
```

Layout :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_container_prev"
        android:layout_width="100.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/left_arrow" android:layout_width="80.0dip" android:layout_height="30.0dip" android:src="@drawable/widget_left_selector" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="110.0dip"
        android:layout_height="34.0dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/logo_ttd"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/loading_container_next" android:layout_width="100.0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/right_arrow" android:layout_width="80.0dip" android:layout_height="30.0dip" android:src="@drawable/widget_right_selector" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So when I press one image the second also took the pressed value, am I missing anything ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, attach click's listeners code for your views.

Comment: I think that's the problem, I'm not done yet with the click listeners :). But in the other hand I added android:clickable="true" to the imageviews and it magically works, so, is it the only issue ?